# Attempting to swap the order of tags changes functionality of Bootstrap/CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am designing a website based around Hockey. I was attempting to create a "carousel" of live games (I did not use Bootstrap 4 carousel). I wanted to flip tags around so that the score would always be on the inside of the teams logo. When I did so, I received a funky side-effect:

[image]

I am currently working on styling when the viewport is between 786px and 991.98px. Viewed any other way and it will not be styled properly.

Ignoring the first box (I was only changing code on the second block denoted under the comment `<--- two --->` in the code below), you'll notice that the scoreblocks in the second box do not match in their styling.

The code below should allow recreation of the issue. (Aside from pointing the css and img to the proper place)

As far as I can tell, the left scoreblock has a "whitespace text node" tag? element? that creates the space between the image and score. However on the right side this "whitespace text node" appears in the div with id score-md and creates the extra background.

```css
@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
    #gameCards {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
    #gameCards {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
    #gameCards {
        display: initial;
    }
    .team-thumbnail {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
    #score-md {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
    #teamScore-md {
        display: initial;
    }
    #teamScore-lg {
        display: none;
    }
    #score-md {
        display: initial;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #gameTime {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    .helper {
        width: 1px;
        height: 1px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    #score-lg {
        display: initial;
    }
    #teamScore-md {
        display: none;
    }
}

#teamScore, #teamScore-lg, #teamScore-md {
    border-width: 2px !important;
}

#gameCards {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 200px;
}

.games-group>.row {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.games-group>.row>.col-md-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}

.games-group>.row>.col-lg-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Customized CSS/Fonts/ETC. -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
   

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>AStats Hockey</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="gameCards" class="container games-group">
        <div class="row text-center bg-secondary flex-nowrap">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 card bg-secondary border-light p-1">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <h6 class="card-title text-white mb-1">NYR at NYR</h6>
                    <div class="row mx-0">
                        <div class="col-4 p-0">
                            <div id="teamScore-md"
                                class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
                                <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0"
                                    src="../../assets/img/teams/New_York_Rangers.svg"></img>
                                <div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark">
                                    <span class="align-top text-white">0</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="teamScore-lg"
                                class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
                                <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0"
                                    src="../../assets/img/teams/New_York_Rangers.svg"></img>
                                <div id="score-lg" class="rounded bg-dark">
                                    <span id="score-lg" class="rounded bg-dark text-white p-1">0</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 p-0 my-auto">
                            <div id="gameTime" class="row rounded bg-dark justify-content-center m-0 p-0">
                                <p class="text-white m-0">End 3rd</p>
                                <p class="text-white m-0">00:00</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <div id="teamScore-md"
                                class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
                                <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0"
                                    src="../../assets/img/teams/New_York_Rangers.svg"></img>
                                <div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark">
                                    <span class="align-top text-white">0</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="teamScore-lg"
                                class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
                                <div id="score-lg" class="rounded bg-dark">
                                    <span id="score-lg" class="rounded bg-dark text-white p-1">0</span>
                                </div>
                                <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0"
                                    src="../../assets/img/teams/New_York_Rangers.svg"></img>
                                <div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark">
                                    <span class="align-top text-white">0</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- two -->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 card bg-secondary border-light p-1">
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <h6 class="card-title text-white mb-1">NYR at NYR</h6>
                    <div class="row mx-0">
                        <div class="col-4 p-0 m-auto">
                            <div id="teamScore-md"
                                class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
                                <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0"
                                    src="../../assets/img/teams/New_York_Rangers.svg"></img>
                                <div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark px-1">
                                    <span class="text-white">0</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="teamScore-lg"
                                class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
                                <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0"
                                    src="../../assets/img/teams/New_York_Rangers.svg"></img>
                                <div id="score-lg" class="rounded bg-dark">
                                    <span id="score-lg" class="rounded bg-dark text-white p-1">0</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 p-0 m-auto">
                            <div id="gameTime" class="row rounded bg-dark justify-content-center m-0 p-0">
                                <p class="text-white m-0">End 3rd</p>
                                <p class="text-white m-0">00:00</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-4 p-0 m-auto">
                            <div id="teamScore-md"
                                class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
                                <div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark px-1">
                                    <span class="text-white">0</span>
                                </div>
                                <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0"
                                    src="../../assets/img/teams/New_York_Rangers.svg"></img>
                            </div>
                            <div id="teamScore-lg"
                                class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
                                <div id="score-lg" class="rounded bg-dark">
                                    <span id="score-lg" class="rounded bg-dark text-white p-1">0</span>
                                </div>
                                <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0"
                                    src="../../assets/img/teams/New_York_Rangers.svg"></img>
                                <div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark">
                                    <span class="align-top text-white">0</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/js/all.js"
        integrity="sha384-eVEQC9zshBn0rFj4+TU78eNA19HMNigMviK/PU/FFjLXqa/GKPgX58rvt5Z8PLs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `#score-md` has `display: inline;`, and whitespaces (including linebreaks) in inline elements are displayed as... well, whitespaces.

You can change `display: initial;` on `#score-md` to `display: inline-block;`, but this will break your layout a little.

The easiest workaround is to remove all whitespaces from `#score-md`, so basically change this:

```
<div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark px-1">
  <span class="text-white">0</span>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark px-1"><span class="text-white">0</span</div>
```

Check snippet below to see how this work.
Also note that I have trimmed your `@media` queries to make example easier to understand.

```css
#gameCards {
  display: initial;
}

.team-thumbnail {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#score-md {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#teamScore-md {
  display: initial;
}

#teamScore-lg {
  display: none;
}

#score-md {
  display: initial;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#gameTime {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.helper {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
}

#teamScore,
#teamScore-lg,
#teamScore-md {
  border-width: 2px !important;
}

#gameCards {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.games-group>.row {
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.games-group>.row>.col-md-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

.games-group>.row>.col-lg-2 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Customized CSS/Fonts/ETC. -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="gameCards" class="container games-group">
  <div class="row text-center bg-secondary flex-nowrap">
    <!-- Card with whitespaces -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 card bg-secondary border-light p-1">
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <h6 class="card-title text-white mb-1">Whitespace</h6>
        <div class="row mx-0">
          <div class="col-4 p-0 m-auto">
            <div id="teamScore-md" class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
              <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/New_York_Rangers.svg">
              <div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark px-1">
                <span class="text-white">0</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 p-0 m-auto">
            <div id="gameTime" class="row rounded bg-dark justify-content-center m-0 p-0">
              <p class="text-white m-0">End 3rd</p>
              <p class="text-white m-0">00:00</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 p-0 m-auto">
            <div id="teamScore-md" class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
              <div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark px-1">
                <span class="text-white">0</span>
              </div>
              <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/New_York_Rangers.svg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Card without whitespaces -->
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 card bg-secondary border-light p-1">
      <div class="card-body p-0">
        <h6 class="card-title text-white mb-1">No whitespace</h6>
        <div class="row mx-0">
          <div class="col-4 p-0 m-auto">
            <div id="teamScore-md" class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
              <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/New_York_Rangers.svg">
              <!-- This inline div is what caused the problem -->
              <div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark px-1"><span class="text-white">0</span></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 p-0 m-auto">
            <div id="gameTime" class="row rounded bg-dark justify-content-center m-0 p-0">
              <p class="text-white m-0">End 3rd</p>
              <p class="text-white m-0">00:00</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-4 p-0 m-auto">
            <div id="teamScore-md" class="row justify-content-center rounded bg-light border border-dark p-1 m-0">
              <!-- This inline div is what caused the problem -->
              <div id="score-md" class="rounded bg-dark px-1"><span class="text-white">0</span></div>
              <img class="team-thumbnail mb-0" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ae/New_York_Rangers.svg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-eVEQC9zshBn0rFj4+TU78eNA19HMNigMviK/PU/FFjLXqa/GKPgX58rvt5Z8PLs7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I feel so dumb, but at the same time I would never of thought that indentation could have side-effects. And yeah my media queries are not done yet, as I've been working from 0px up.  Thank you so much!!